# How to unblock extensions in Safari so I can install adblock?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

I'm trying to install AdBlock Plus so pages like beliefnet.com won't have so many ads. Safari says my extensions are blocked.  HELP?

Comment: And in Safari, the Help menu, searching "extensions" didn't get you an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Safari has Extensions turned on by going to Safari > Preferences > Extensions and slide the On/Off switch to On.